# Best IDE for Android programming(especially for java coding)?

Tags: java, android, ide

Tell Best IDE for Android programming

Comment: eclipse, IntelliJ, Android Studio

Comment: Please search next time before you ask. This has been discussed multiple times before. Also don't ask for "the best" cause it may result in opinion based answers.

Comment: check https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The official IDE for android dev is now [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

You can also use Eclipse with adt plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Use Android Studio is the official recommended IDE for Android development.

Comment: Ohh yeah... downvote cause it is so wrong right? Comment before you downvote.

Comment: That's what you get when you answer obvious off-topic questions, I suppose, you shouldn't act so surprised...

Answer (score 1):

Sigh, I would go for the [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)  or [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/)..

Comment: android studio and eclips both but latest lib supported to android studio